# Dispatching Two Actions

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component that has a `_handleOnClick` method. When the `_handleOnClick` function is fired, it dispatches an action through `updateCanDrinkFlag` which updates `canDrink` in the redux state which in turn updates `this.props.canDrink`. In addition, another action is dispatched if it fits a conditional check through `updateCanDriveFlag` which updates `canDrive` in the redux state which in turn updates `this.props.canDrive`.

The below code works as expected:
If initially `this.props.canDrink` is `true` and `this.props.canDrive` is `true`
after the click, `this.props.canDrink` is `false` and `this.props.canDrive` is `false`

would there be a case where this code might not work? For example, in my conditional statement, I am checking for `this.props.canDrink === true` which is what the value is originally before `updateCanDrinkFlag` runs. Will there be a case where the `updateCanDrinkFlag` completes (changes my redux state and `this.props.canDrink` changes to false) before the if statement runs?

```
export default class Item extends PureComponent {
    //this.props.canDrink is true
    //this.props.canDrive is true

    _handleOnClick = () => {  
        //updates canDrink to false          
        updateCanDrinkFlag({
            id,
            value: !this.props.canDrink,
        });

        // if updating canDrink to false and canDrive is true, update canDrive to false too
        if (this.props.canDrink && this.props.canDrive) {
            updateCanDriveFlag({
                id,
                value: false,
            });
        }
    }

...

}
```

Comment: No, I don't think so. Both actions are dispatched *during* the same render cycle, so I don't believe there's a way for the callback handler to still be processing/executing and a state update occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no. Your code is technically fine. But I must comment that, your code is not optimal in style.

If I were you, I would do the synchronization logic (if canDrink == false && canDrive == true then canDrive = false) *inside reducer*, instead of firing another action here.

Your current code check against:

```
if (this.props.canDrink && this.props.canDrive) { ... }
```

which is actually:

```
if (this.props.canDrink /* which implies nextProps.canDrive == false */ 
    && this.props.canDrive
) { ... }
```

IT'S JUST SO CONFUSING! That's also precisely why you ask this question in the first place cus you worry about it.

If you do it inside reducer, then the problem is gone.

```
switch (action.type) {
  case updateCanDrinkFlag:
    const { canDrink, id } = action.payload;
    state[id].canDrink = canDrink;
    // synchronize two fields here:
    if (!canDrink) state[id].canDrive = false;
}
```

---

#### Side note

I'm not sure how your knowledge about Redux is, there's something I'd like to
 bring up. I quote you:

> Will there be a case where the `updateCanDrinkFlag` completes (changes my redux state and `this.props.canDrink` changes to false)...

Note that these are 2 different things that happens *asynchronously*. When `updateCanDrinkFlag` completes, it only changes your redux state. Updating `this.props.canDrink` is not its job.

When you `dispatch(ActionOfUpdateCanDrinkFlag)`, this is what happen **inside** `dispatch` if you [unbox it](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.ts#L246):

```
function dispatch(action) {
  // ...
  currentState = reducer(prevState, action)
  // ...
}
```

See, the reducer is actually completed. And the internal state of a redux store is already updated, and the store also send a signal to React to notify that internal state change. These things happens synchronously.

However, when react to that signal and sync `props` with `store.getState()` is leave for React to decide, and this phase happens asynchronously.